# Optimized C# equivalent of tsql "in (value1, value2)"?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In SQL you can write something like
     if value in (value1,value2) then ... else ...

In C# it would be nice to write

```
 A) if( value == (value1 or value2) ) { ... }
```

Or

```
 B) if( value in (value1, value2) ) { ... }
```

Of course you can already write:

```
 C) if( new[]{value1, value2}.Contains(value) )
```

But this code is slow as it builds a new array.

Which one do you like best ?

Comment: If you want to have a universal solution you will have to have a collection  (implementing Enumerable) of some sort to pass anyway - and in that case you are not creating a new one. And if it is just few values, than really - you are not wasting that much of memory to fight for better solution over time and readability of your code.

Answer (score 2):

If `value1` and `value2` are always the same, I'd build a collection (whether a set, an array, a list or whatever) once, and store them in a static variable.

Otherwise, I'd probably write:

```
if (value == value1 || value == value2)
```

If I had several values, then for readability I *would* create the collection - but with just two values I probably wouldn't bother - the above more readable than the array-creating form, IMO.

*If* I'd gone for the collection-creating form, I would then *consider* optimizing back to the non-collection-creating form only when I'd discovered that the application was too slow and proved that it was due to creating the collection.

In other words:

- Simplicity first (comparing two values with `==` and `||` is fine)
- Simplicity again (create a collection when it *genuinely* improves simplicity)
- Performance only when it's been tested and found to be important in this piece of code
- Simplicity and performance together where possible (using a single "constant" collection where that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

If it's only two or three values I would use `if (value == value1 || value == value2)` otherwise you could use your third way, but make the array static if it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the performance balance that you want to achieve and the size of your data set.

**If** you can afford a relatively expensive construction **and** the lookup is absolutely critical performance-wise **and** the lookup happens frequently compared to construction **and** the number of items is large enough to justify it all, construct a new `HashSet`, then use `HashSet.Contains`.

If, on the other hand, you only have few items, having `if (value == value1 || value == value2 /* Etc.. */)` is probably good enough. Just be careful to "sort" your values from most-likely-to-match to least-likely-to-match. For example, if `value2` tends to match more frequently than `value1`, rewrite the above "if" as: `if (value == value2 || value == value1)` so the `||` operator can perform its short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to have a construct easier to read than a serie of IF when you have few non constant items.
I will suggest the C# team to add a contruct like this in C# next :

if( value in (value1, value2) ) { ... }

which should expand to a temporary collection and use Contains, or a const collection if all values are constants.